# Getting street view POV to always be facing the street

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I need to enter an address and have the street view panorama always facing down the street.  I thought I could do this with computeHeading by using my target location and a neighboring location, but if I use that it does not always face the down the street.  I noticed when in panorama view the arrows always face the correct direction.  Is there a way to cue off of the arrows and point my panorama in the same direction?  I did see some sample code in V2 where there are driving apps that drive down the street in the correct direction, but those examples do not apply to V3.  If anyone can help, thanks!